# Nested system naming convention in Common Lisp using ASDF?

Tags: common-lisp, naming-conventions, asdf

Could not find anything concrete online. Forgive me if I don't use the appropriate lingo for CL terms.

I have a large utility library written in Lisp. It became large enough that I found it prudent to split it into multiple components.

Using ASDF, I made one master system, called `libname`, which is defined by a top-level `libname.asd`, which uses subsystems each containing their own `.asd` file.

My question is this: What is the appropriate naming conventions for the subsystems? The subsystems are independent enough s.t. they can be used without other subsystems. I can share or use the subsystems without loading the master system. Right now, I use a prefix for each system, e.g. `libname-subsys-a`, defined by `libname-subsys-a.asd`, whose interface is provided by `libname-subsys-a.lisp`. Should I reconsider the prefix?

Note that the master system offers nothing except to group all the subsystems under a common system, s.t. loading its dependencies is made simpler.

Comment: I don't think there is a convention.  Yours is as probably as good as any.  I use *x* `/` *y* (without spaces) where *x* is system name (itself as a domain-separated name) and *y* is some subsystem (so `org.my-domain.my-overall-system/tests`).  But where the subsystem is not just a test system I'd use *x* `.` *y* (so `org.my-domain.my-overall-system.my-independent-subsystem`).